# Using REGEXEXTRACT on an IMPORTRANGE in Google Docs

Tags: regex, google-sheets-formula, google-docs

I am importing a range from another Google sheet and I need to pull a specific number from the data that is imported. The data looks something like:

R2.word.4.word

I want to extract the second number. It will always follow this format (a letter and a number then a period then a word then a period then a number (might be single or double digit) then a period and a word). The regex to extract the second number should be: (\d+)(?!.*\d) and I have tested it in multiple regex test sites. However, Google docs gives me an error stating it is not a regular expression. I tried something like this (edited out URL and the sheet name):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTRANGE(URL,Sheet!A2:A200), "(\d+)(?!.*\d"))
```

Can anyone help me understand how I can fix this?

And the other issue here is that it isn't actually importing the range. I only get it to import on the first cell and not down the column.

Answer (score 4):

You could write a pattern like:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"^[A-Z]\d+\.\w+\.(\d+)")
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z]` Match a single uppercase char
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `\.` Match a dot
- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `\.` Match a dot
- `(\d+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yrzOUl/1)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following regex.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"^[a-zA-Z]\d+\.[^.]*\.(\d+)\.\S+$")
```

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/W9d4KS/1) for above regex.

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
^[a-zA-Z]  ##From starting of value matching a-zA-Z here.
\d+        ##Matching 1 or more occurrences of digits.
\.[^.]*\.  ##Matching literal dot till next occurrence of dot here.
(\d+)      ##Creating 1 capturing group and which has 1 or more digits matching in it.
\.\S+$     ##Matching literal dot followed by 1o or more non-spaces till end of value.
```

Answer (score 2):

> "*It will always follow this format*"

Based on the above; you can use `REGEXEXTRACT()` but it's slow compared to simple `SPLIT()` which in your standardized format is ideal:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A3,"."),0,3)
```

This is an array-formula by default and will spill all values down. Just apply it to your entire range.

Comment: Thank you, how do I use SPLIT with IMPORTRANGE. I keep getting an error.

Comment: What is your attempt? You know that importrange needs string variables? @Ann